# Using ncol(.) argument in rename_with function gives error: Error in 2:ncol(.) : argument of length 0

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename

I'm trying to rename all my columns in my data frame/tibble.

The idea is to give the first column a specific/dedicated name and then all other columns a "consecutive" name with a subscript at the end. For the subscript I tried to use the ncol(.) function, but keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

What am I missing here?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 col2 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 col3 = c(1, 2, 3)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename_with(.cols = everything(),
              .fn   = ~c("new_col_1", paste0("test_", 2:ncol(.))))

# Error in 2:ncol(.) : argument of length 0
```

FYI, changing the `2:ncol(.)` part above to `2:3` then works, but I want to pass this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with tidyverse non-standard evaluation. If you want to change the name of every column, you could easily exchange `rename_with` with base-R's `setNames` function (which happens to fit nicely in a pipe too):

```
data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 col2 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 col3 = c(1, 2, 3)) %>%
  setNames(c("new_col_1", paste0("test_", 2:ncol(.))))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
new_col_1 test_2 test_3
<dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
  1         1      1      1
  2         2      2      2
  3         3      3      3
```

Comment: Works nicely. Do you have any more details (or a good source for starters) on the reason why the rename_with doesn't work with the ncol function? Not being an expert I thought the cool thing with the tidyverse is that you can pass whatever is the "result" of the previous pipe with `whatever(.)`, so it feels odd that this particular one isn't working, but a base R function is.

Comment: In this particular case, there are at least two problems. The first one is that the `.` is in a formula (started with the `~` character). The pipe can only insert arguments into functions, but not into formulas. 
The second is, that in tidyverse, formulas of this kind are interpreted as anonymus functions, and `.` is used to refer to the argument of this function. In your situation the `.` is interpreted in this way. This is also what causes the error.
(Try executing `2:ncol(c("a", "b"))`. Here `c("a", "b")` plays the role of the argument to the anonymus function - the original columnnames.)

Comment: ok, I partially understand at least. Would you see any way how I could paste/use the ncol parameter nonetheless in a tidyverse function / formula?

Comment: The problem is not the `ncol`, its the `.` as it does not refer do teh data.frame as a whole, but to the argument of the anonymus function. 
Since the anonymus function gets the original names as input you can just replace `ncol` with `length` in your original code.

Comment: Like this:
`rename_with(.cols = everything(), .fn   = ~c("new_col_1", paste0("test_", 2:length(.))))`

In other contexts, tidyverse also offers "context dependet expressions" that can help (but they don't work with rename): https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can simply use:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0('test_', 1:ncol(df))
```